# Chrome Zoom out (cntrl - ) in windows hides the linear gradient stripes color

Tags: html, css, background-image, linear-gradients

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<div style="background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #e7e7e7, #e7e7e7 1px, #ffffff 1px, #ffffff 24px);position: absolute;width: inherit;height: 487px;"></div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNRVG.png)

Comment: try increasing the width of lines and see

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `position:fixed` will help instead of `position:absolute`. Wrap the content `div` with a wrapper and apply `overflow` to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't apply position fixed it's breaks my UI. If I apply also it's not working

Comment: May be it's your css conflict.